# How to test latency from user to server in browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to gather some information using the visitors of my websites.
What I need is for each visitor to ping 3 different hostnames and then save the following info into a DB.

```
Visitor IP, latency 1,latency 2, latency 3
```

Of course everything has to be transparent for the visitor without interrupting him in any way.
Is this possible? Can you give me an example? Are there any plugins for jQuery or something to make it easier

**EDIT**

This is what I have so far [jsfiddle.net/dLVG6](http://jsfiddle.net/dLVG6) but the data is too random. It jumps from 50 to 190

Answer (score 8):

This is going to be more of a pain that you might think.

Your first problem is that Javascript doesn't have ping.  Mostly what Javascript is good at is HTTP and a few cousin protocols.

Second problem is that you can't just issue some ajax requests and time the results (that would be way too obvious).  The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent you from using ajax to talk to servers other than the one the page came from.  You'll need to use JSONP, or change the src of an image tag, or something else more indirect.

Your third problem is that you don't want to do anything that will result in a lot of data being returned.  You don't want data transfer time or extensive server processing to interfere with measuring latency.

Fourth, you can't ask for URLs that might be cached.  If the object happened to be in the cache, you would get really low "latency" measurements but it wouldn't be meaningful.

My solution was to use an image tag with no `src` attribute.  On document load, set the `src` to point to a valid server but use an invalid port.  Generally, it is faster for a server to simply reject your connection than to generate a proper 404 error response.  All you have to do then is measure how long it takes to get the error event from the image.

From [The Filddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLWHS/):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
$('#junkOne').attr('src', 'http://fate.holmes-cj.com:8886/').error(function () {
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    $('#timer').html("" + (end - start) + "ms");
});
```

The technique could probably be improved.  Here's some ideas:

1. Use IP address instead of DNS host name.
2. Do the "ping" multiple times, throw out the highest and lowest scores, then average the rest.
3. If your web page has a lot heavy processing going on, try to do the tests when you think the UI load is lightest.

Comment: Nice, but I'm not sure I can use this. Requiring HTML content is not a best case senario. This is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/dLVG6/ but the data is too random. It jumps from 50 to 190

Comment: You don't understand. The whole point is to query a port that will reject your connection.  No HTML content is required.  In fact, you don't want any content at all.

Comment: Your code requires an element called junkOne. I was hoping to work without it

Comment: Yes, but it is necessary.  You can hide the element.  Just because you're using it doesn't mean you have to show it.

Comment: @slashingweapon I fixed your answer so that it actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/ve3z0589/5/  It is better to use a standard web server port with something that will 404 in most cases.  Your example only works if the web server handles port 8886 and rejects it quickly, but using an invalid port triggers a long browser timeout, so it's not accurate at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That machine is down now, which is another reason the connection would linger.   The technique as written still works on machines nearby me, but for some reason doing this with machines farther away causes a long delays instead of fast fails.  Someone who knows the TCP protocol well and is up-to-date on modern routing could probably explain why.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you could:
`$.ajax(url,settings)`(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and take the time from `beforeSend` and on `complete` via `Date.now()`, subtract those times -> then you have the time for the request (not excactly the "Ping" though)

Comment: Just a note that this approach will encounter additional latency if a DNS lookup is required (not sure if question should include DNS lookup time as part of the latency, if applicable).

Comment: I tried it but the data is too random. I added a demo you can checkout

Comment: Your fiddle ends up caching the js-file, you should do something like this to prevent caching: http://jsfiddle.net/dLVG6/1/

Comment: I get the same random data

Comment: I don't think this is working.  If you look at the dev tools in Chrome, you'll see that the request gets cancelled.  You can't issue an Ajax call to a different host.  (Actually, some browsers let you do so, but you have to set the right params.  Even then, some browsers won't allow cross-origin requests at all.)

Answer (score 1):

2021:

Tried this again for a React app I'm building. I don't think the accuracy is too great.

```
const ping = () => {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    api.get('/ping').then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(`${end-start} ms`)
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
};
```

Wrote my own little API, but I suppose there's just way too much going on during the request.

In terminal, I get about 23ms ping to my server.. using this it shoots up to like 200-500ms.